# How do you get a converted request from RestTemplate after a GET/POST/PUT call?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

I have no issues using Spring's RestTemplate to make POST or GET calls to an endpoint. I've also set the message converter as JSON (MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter), no prob.

My question is, how can I grab the converted request I'm sending?

Example, if I do this:

```
ResponseEntity<T> result = this.restTemplate.postForEntity("http://{endpoint_url...}", dtoEntryObj, SomeDTO.class);
```

How could I grab the JSON that it's sending to the endpoint?

Comment: Wouldn't it be in dtoEntryObj?

Comment: No, because that's the source object I'm passing in. You can pretend it's a Map or List, or whatever. RestTemplate is automatically converting it since I set my message converter.

Answer (score 0):

`RestTemplate` can send formats other than json as well. To get the actual body of the request, you will need to implement your own `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and use `RestTemplate#setInterceptors()` to register it.

Something like

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
ClientHttpRequestInterceptor interceptor = new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor() {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
            ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        // you have access to the body
        // do something with it
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
};
template.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(interceptor));
```

Note that with json, `RestTemplate` uses a `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` which internally uses an `ObjectMapper`. You can simulate it if the above solution doesn't work for you.